# Manual update modules

Tags: updating, 7

I'm trying to update the drupal commons contributed modules but i can't run the automatic updates via ftp because i'm working on aws ec2 server and i don't have the ftp access but only sftp+ssh (+ aws key path). Is there any way to make a manual update of these modules? I don't see the contributed modules directories in /html/modules/ even in html/sites/all/modules/.
I also have tried to put the new unzipped modules folders directly in /html/sites/all/modules and after run the database update but i get some errors.
What is the right way? 
Thanks

Comment: since ur using drupal commons the modules might be in a diff folder. Since they are considered as default modules and not extensions. look at all ur folders in html.

Comment: Maybe in `/profiles/commons/modules`?

Comment: Yes Clive! thanks! `/profiles/commons/modules/` inside there is `commons` and `contrib`. Thank you!

Comment: I've another problem now... when i try to install new modules via linux commands `tar -zxvf /sites/all/moduels/module.tar.gz` or `unzip /sites/all/moduels/module.zip` and after reload the modules page on my drupal commons website i get a white page error server... any idea?